# Do scriptures support the offering of Turmeric to Shivling?

Tags: scripture, shiva, worship, shiva-purana, shiva-lingam

Many people oppose the offering of Turmeric (Haldi) on Shivling by claiming that Haldi is of feminin nature while Shivling  is of masculine. By that logic, Kumkum should also be prohibited for Shivling as it is also related to females, but Lingashtakam, shlok 5 allows offering of kumkum. So is offering Haldi to shivling allowed or not as per the scriptures?

Comment: *Many people oppose*, but does śāstra oppose? If śāstra doesn't oppose, why should one make up a niṣedha by one's own self?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Siva Puran says in one place:-
[image: excerpt from Siva Puran]

Rice grains beautified with turmeric powder. Specifically the rice grain is being adorned.

Traditionally turmeric itself is believed to be feminine and not to be used as an offering.

Comment: Please have a look at: https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1137/20129 and https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/616/use-ocr-to-post-answers-from-pdfs-which-are-not-text-searchable?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C37.9393

Comment: @Adiyarkku - many thanks.